# Windows Phone ListPicker in fullscreen mode does not show item value

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

I've just started with WP 7.1. I tried the C# LocalDatabaseSample on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
I tried to modify the Listpicker (in the AddNewItem sreen) to let the user choose an item from a list. It works well when there are 3 items in the list. However, when there are about 30 items, the Listpicker goes to fullscreen mode, and it does not show the item value, but something like "LocalDatabaseSample.Model.ToDoCategory".

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at retemplating the `FullModeItemTemplate` for the listpicker and/or overriding `ToString` on your model.

Comment: Thank you, I did some research about it but still there are not many references about FullModeItemTemplate. Can you tell a bit more details about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's just teh item template that is displayed when the listpicker is displayed in full screen mode. See an example of customizing it at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1